# I would like to change some contents in template from overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I am writing my dissertation, I used the template from overleaf. The template can be found by the keywords ua-thesis.cls. In the first page of the template, the dissertation was submitted to Graduate Interdisciplinary Program in Applied Mathematics. I would like to change it to my program. However, I didn't find a place to change it. I think it's from the document class ua-thesis.cls. But I can only see .tex file at overleaf. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ua-thesis is part of TeX Live (https://ctan.org/pkg/uaclasses), so it's hard to see how its commands are defined when looking at the Overleaf template (the .cls and .sty files are not shown in the project, as they are provided by TeX Live). You may want to download the zip from CTAN and compile it locally to see what commands are provided. Looking at ua-title.sty, you can see that the department can be set by \department{}, which you can provide in your preamble.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that was helpful. BTW, if your question seems more Overleaf specific (rather than a LaTeX question), it's best to send it to support@overleaf.com.